# multiple if in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to query the country according to currency.

```
    WHEN(odr."foreignCurrency" = "INR") THEN "india"
    WHEN(odr."foreignCurrency" = "Ringgit") THEN "Malaysia" 
    END
    AS "country"
```

the country is not my data table. I just want to see data in the country column. In foreignCurrency column, there are data like INR, Ringgit

Comment: That's invalid SQL to begin with. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes - double quotes are only used for identifiers (e.g. table or column names)

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, like column names. Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: There are a *lot* of countries and currencies. Instead of trying to write a huge CASE that covers all of them create a table with `Currency` and `Country` columns and join with it. The `foreignCurrency` column seems to contain dirty data though - both currency codes and currency names

Answer (score 0):

You can use this resource from a kind guy,
This is query to create a table and Insert data for currency, country, code as well as symbol.

https://gist.github.com/voskobovich/43f851859c23a8261514

Once you have currency table, you can use values from join or its MV.

Also found this one Postgres Documentation, for datatype money, might help in future if currency value conversions are required.

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-money](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-money.html)